# What's the name of the figure of speech where a person departs from the main stream of thought for the purpose of explanation or added information?

Tags: single-word-requests, figures-of-speech, interjections

What is a departure from the main stream of thought for the purpose of explanation or added information? Is it called an interjection?

Answer (score 5):

It's what I'd usually call a [**digression:**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/digression)

> NOUN
>
> A temporary departure from the main subject in speech or writing:
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *Let’s return to the main topic after that brief digression*
>
> *Except for a few meandering authorial digressions, the novel maintains a cracking pace from start to finish.*
>
> *Anyhow, digressions aside, this guy was completely incapable of performing his job with any degree of skill.*
>
> *As such, his writings express the digressions, meanderings, meditations, ruminations and speculations that characterise a singular, idiosyncratic mind at work.*

You could also call it an [**aside:**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aside)

> NOUN
>
> 2 A remark that is not directly related to the main topic of discussion:
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *The recipe book has little asides about the importance of home and family.*
>
> *One wonders what these asides are supposed to achieve.*
>
> *You'll have to tolerate the digressions, the asides, the off-the-cuff remarks.*
>
> *The next three posts will be a detailed account of the lectures and the question-and-answer session, with comments about the audience and a few asides from me.*

[**Interjection**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/interjection) has two main senses. The one that is most relevant to your question is described at point 1 below:

> NOUN
>
> 1 An abrupt remark, made especially as an aside or interruption.
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *Conversely, the interjection of an apology into this situation yields several ameliorative results.*
>
> *My colleague John Key interjects with the best interjection of all.*
>
> *When a person asking a question chooses to make an unnecessary and offensive remark, he is inviting an interjection at that point.*
>
> 1.1 An exclamation, especially as a part of speech, e.g., ah! or dear me!.
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *In English, conjunctions, determiners, interjections, particles, and pronouns are grammatical words.*
>
> *I am working on a book about the parts of speech - that's right, nouns, verbs, interjections and all the rest.*
>
> *Two significant categories, of course - an article lacking interjections and pronouns, for example, would not pack the punch of one without any nouns or verbs.*

(All definitions and examples taken from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: Within a sentence, digressions and explanatory extensions are two varieties of _parentheticals_.